# Can't find Docker data volume on host

Tags: docker, vagrant, volume, host, coreos

I have *CoreOS* running inside a *Vagrant* box. My working directory is `/home/core`.

I then run `docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins`. The container starts without any problems.

Unfortunately I can't find the mounted volume inside my Vagrant box. I assumed it would be in `/home/core/jenkins_home` but it ain't there. `/home/core/` is empty.

Where is this directory?

Comment: you mounted it in /var/jenkins_home... why it sould be in /home/core/?

Comment: @Gabbax0r As I understand the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/) the first parameter is the host directory.

Comment: In your volume mapping, try to use  an absolute path (i.e. /home/core/jenkins), instead of a relative path (jenkins_home).

Comment: @HyL Yes, this works too. But out of curiosity I wonder where my data is gone with a relative path …

Comment: To solve your curiosity: First, ```docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins``` RUN this again. Then,  ```docker volume ls``` will show the volume list with volume name; ```docker volume inspect <volume_name>``` will show you the full path of your Mountpoint.

Answer (score 0):

The advice to use an absolute host path for volumes is in the comments (hat tip @Hy L), but the question of where the data went with the relative path was still an open issue. I'm on WSL2 and I finally found my data at

```
/mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/data/docker
```

and I needed `sudo` to look inside the following directory to see data from my relative mount (`pipeline_runs`):

```
sudo ls volumes/pipeline_runs/_data
```

I don't have a full understanding but I take it that this is where the Hyper-V machine is storing its data, so when you specify a relative path, it's actually relative to a path on that (virtual) machine.